# Why is self not the class instance when using scikit-learn pipelines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

As you can read from the title, `self` from a class instance is not the class instance itself.

This happens when I use a custom class with scikit-learn pipelines, but not when I use the same custom class separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

class multi_feature_OHE(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    ''' Encode multiple redundant features as one, usign One-Hot-Encoder. '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

    def fit(self, X):
        #self.encoder.fit(X)
        print(type(self))    # <--- We print the type of self here!
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        ...
```

Here it prints `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(...,
                         multi_feature_OHE)
pipeline.fit(data)
```

In the `fit` method, `self` == `X` and `X` == `None`.

But here it prints `<class '__main__.multi_feature_OHE'>`

```
a = multi_feature_OHE()
a.fit(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to pass an *instance* of the class to the pipeline, you are passing the class object itself, **there is no instance**. So do something like:

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(...,
                         multi_feature_OHE())
pipeline.fit(data)
```

Look at the example in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline)

Basically, the pipeline will take whatever object and call `.fit(X)` on it. If you pass just the class object, then `multi_feature_OHE.fit` is just the plain function, so the first argument will take the array from the last transformation.

Look at the example in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline)

```
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), GaussianNB(priors=None))
Pipeline(steps=[('standardscaler', StandardScaler()),
                ('gaussiannb', GaussianNB())])
```